# What is the usage of lambda trailing return type auto?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, language-lawyer, trailing-return-type

What is the usage of adding `-> auto` in `[]() -> auto { return 4; }`?

For me - it is not different than `[]() { return 4; }`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is `auto` by default. The Standard, [[expr.prim.lambda]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#4), reads:

> If a *lambda-expression* does not include a *lambda-declarator*, it is as if the *lambda-declarator* were `()`. The lambda return type is `auto`, which is replaced by the *trailing-return-type* if provided and/or deduced from `return` statements as described in [dcl.spec.auto].

**My addition.**

So, `-> auto` itself is not useful. However, we can form other return types with `auto`, namely: `-> auto&`, `-> const auto&`, `-> auto&&`, `-> decltype(auto)`. Standard [rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) of return type deduction apply. One should bear in mind that `auto` is never deduced to be a reference type, so by default a lambda returns a non-reference type.

A few (trivial) examples:

```
// 1.
int foo(int);
int& foo(char);

int x;

auto lambda1 = [](auto& x) { return x; };
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(lambda1(x)), int>);

auto lambda2 = [](auto& x) -> auto& { return x; };
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(lambda2(x)), int&>);

// 2.
auto lambda3 = [](auto x) { return foo(x); };
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(lambda3(1)), int>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(lambda3('a')), int>);

auto lambda4 = [](auto x) -> decltype(auto) { return foo(x); };
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(lambda4(1)), int>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(lambda4('a')), int&>);

// 3.
auto lambda5 = [](auto&& x) -> auto&& { return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x); };
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(lambda5(x)), int&>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(lambda5(foo(1))), int&&>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(lambda5(foo('a'))), int&>);
```

---

**PiotrNycz's addition.** As pointed out in comments (credit to @StoryTeller) - the real usage is version with `auto&` and `const auto&` and "The degenerate case is just not something worth bending backwards to disallow."

See:

```
int p = 7;
auto p_cr = [&]()  -> const auto& { return p; };
auto p_r = [&]()  -> auto& { return p; };
auto p_v = [&]()  { return p; }; 

const auto& p_cr1 = p_v(); // const ref to copy of p
const auto& p_cr2 = p_cr(); // const ref to p
p_r() = 9; // we change p here

std::cout << p_cr1 << "!=" << p_cr2 << "!\n";
// print 7 != 9 !
```

Comment: Do you know maybe - why for c++11 this code does not compile? Your answer suggests that this default is here from the very beginning (what for lambda is C++11). Was that some fix ?

Comment: @PiotrNycz, there was no `auto` return type for functions in C++11. In C++11 you can't write `auto foo() { return 4; }`. It's a C++14 feature.

Comment: @PiotrNycz - Bear in mind that the C++14 rule allows `decltype(auto)`, `auto&&`, `auto const&` and so forth. The degenerate case is just not something worth bending backwards to disallow.

Comment: @StoryTeller that makes sense!  I see usages for `-> auto const&` and others. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @PiotrNycz, `-> decltype(auto)` and `-> auto&&` can also be useful. Consider, for example, a lambda taking `auto&& var`.