# Function that takes multiple variadic arguments: sumfunc(auto... a, auto... b)

Tags: c++, c++17

How to write such a function that takes multiple variadic arguments and does something with them (for example,  sum them up if they're of samem type)?

For example, the code snippet works fine:

```
auto someFunc = [](auto a, auto b) -> auto { return a + b; };

auto curry = [](auto func) -> auto
{
    return [=](auto x) -> auto
    {
        return [=](auto y) -> auto { return x + y; };
    };
};
```

Calling this with currying also works:

```
std::cout << (someFunc)(10, 5) << std::endl;
std::cout << curry(someFunc)(10)(18) << std::endl;
```

Now how to do the same when somefunc() has the following kind of a signature?

```
auto someFunc = [](auto... a, auto... b) -> auto { return ??? ; };
```

If there is no such way, can this be done using C++17 Fold ops?

Thanks.

Comment: "sum them up ..." Sounds a lot like [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: Use tuples maybe?

Comment: when both are same type it is impossible to know where `a` ends and `b` starts

Comment: you could use only one variadic argument and some sentinel type to indicate where `b` starts

Comment: https://ideone.com/Yvj2t8

Comment: Don't use `-> auto`, it is `auto` by default: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52077143/1625187

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. What does it mean for `someFunc` to take _two_ packs? Do you mean just one pack? Do you have an example? Is the question how to `curry` a function that could take more than two arguments? Need... a lot more info here.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thanks for the suggestion, tried tuple and vector<any> to unpack the arguments, but couldn't make it work. Could you please give an example of how to do that and call? Thanks.

Comment: @Evg Thanks, point noted, removed ->auto.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks a lot. was trying to do exactly similar and your code worked. But, in case I want to say, add two such auto... , how can I do that? I assume they are of same type, of course. So I need to somehow demarcate them. Thanks.

Comment: this is a good example how from simple problem, create over-engineered crap code since some langue feature is "cool". This is classic example of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) so please describe X.